# How to delete all datasets with names starting with a specific text in Azure Data Factory using Azure Powershell?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Iam trying to delete only specific datasets in the datafactory,i.e, only those whose names start with say, "DS_SHP". Iam using azure powershell cmdlets like:
 Get-AzureRmDataFactoryDataset -ResourceGroupName "cdm-apps-rg" -DataFactoryName "cdm-apps-adf" | Remove-AzureRmDataFactoryDataset -Force

But the above deletes all the datasets. 
Any idea how to delete only specific datasets in bulk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter the output first from `Get-AzureRmDataFactoryDataset`. Pipe the cmd into "where" like this example, then pipe that into Remove-`AzureRmDataFactoryDataset`.

```
Get-AzureRmDataFactoryDataset 
  -ResourceGroupName "cdm-apps-rg" 
  -DataFactoryName "cdm-apps-adf" 
  | Where {$_.DatasetName -like 'DS_SHP*'} 
  | Remove-AzureRmDataFactoryDataset 
     ResourceGroupName "cdm-apps-rg" 
    -DataFactoryName "cdm-apps-adf"
```

Comment: Mark is correct. I'll add that you don't need to specify the resource group and data factory names again to the Remove cmdlet when piping this way, since it will use the objects as input and each object knows the factory it belongs to

Comment: Thanks it worked. Just for the benefit of other users new to ADF, we can add -Force to delete the required datasets without prompting you for confirmation.